# Django Single View to get response from multiple apps

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have following apps:

```
├── events
├── files
├── pictures
├── posts
├── thoughts
└── videos
```

Here events, files, pictures, thoughts, videos all come under the category of **posts**.
Now I want to achieve a single endpoint to handle saving/retrieval of all types of posts mentioned.
For that I will receive all incoming requests in **posts/views.py** and the call views of the desired app based on the type of post.

I cannot merge the different kinds of posts into one as each kind of post has different attributes and models and I want to make them pluggable.

In Django each view must return a HTTPResponse, so how can I call views.py of files,videos etc and then return the response from posts itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very same way you'd do for just any function, why ?

```
def postview(request, *args, **kw):
    post_type = guess_the_post_type_from(request)
    view = get_the_view_for(post_type)
    return view(request, *args, **kw)
```